# Nginx - Separate WebRoot for subdirectories

Tags: nginx

I am trying to set a separate web root for each subdirectory in my nginx.conf file below.

I thought this was the correct approach, however when I echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] from each I receive the same result (/var/www/htdocs).

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong and point me in the right direction?

```
server { 
  listen 80; 
  listen [::]:80; 

  server_name testing.local;

  root /var/www/htdocs/desktop;
  index index.html index.php;
  autoindex on;

  location /tablet {
      root /var/www/htdocs/tablet;
      index index.html index.php;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

      location ~ \.php$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
          fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          include fastcgi_params;
      }
  }

  location /mobile {
    root /var/www/htdocs/mobile;
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to the file is constructed by concatenating the value of `root` with the URI, so in your configuration you have `mobile` and `tablet` specified in the pathname twice! See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

The `^~` modifier to the `location` directive is necessary to raise its precedence order so that the nested location can process PHP files. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location ^~ /mobile {
    root /var/www/htdocs;
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
    }
}
```